# javascript fulltext search framework with multilingual support

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, lunrjs

i need to do fulltext search via javascript on client-side.
I found [lunr](http://lunrjs.com/). It is great, but i need multilingual support.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** There is a project ([lunr-languages](https://github.com/MihaiValentin/lunr-languages)) that provides support for multiple languages, the currently supported languages are:

- German
- French
- Spanish
- Italian
- Japanese
- Dutch
- Danish
- Portuguese
- Finnish
- Romanian
- Hungarian
- Russian
- Norwegian

---

[Multi-language support](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.js/tree/i18n) is coming to lunr in the next release. There are already adapters for [french](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.fr.js) and [russian](https://github.com/olivernn/lunr.ru.js), which languages do you need to support?

I only speak English so testing the quality of these adapters is difficult for me, I'm always looking for support from people who have a need for the other language adapters with testing etc.

You can take a look at either the French or Russian adapters to see what is required, you just need to create a [stemmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) for the required language and implement a [stop word list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) containing very common words in the language.